# How to do positive and negative search at once using linux

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, vi

I have a log file

```
 abc12357657868</Response>
 123567575</Response>
 abcgiututyb</Response>
 6786uhj</Response>
 abc Hello world
```

I want to display lines which do not have abc but has `</Response>`

I want that line 2 and line 4 be outputted.How can I use grep command to achieve that. I was also hoping that I can display 3 lines above from the line of match

Also can I count such number of lines using linux command?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `grep '</Response>' logfile | grep -v 'abc' | wc -l`?

Comment: Or `grep -v abc logfile | grep -c '</Response>'`

Comment: **I was also hoping that I can display 3 lines above from the line of match** Could you show your full log file and also what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thank you @Phylogenesis : it worked fine. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @mathB : I was looking to display 3 lines above. I used -b3 option and it worked fine. Thank you